# PHP Mailparse attachments

Tags: php, attachment

I am developing a small email system and have a question about PHP Mailparse which I can't seem to find an answer to, nor figure out from the code itself.  I've spent a bunch of time going through the Mailparse code and can't see an answer.

Simply, is there any way of discerning between images which are attached to an incoming email and those which are embedded in the email (e.g. signature images at the foot of the email).

Mailparse seems to deliver both attached files and embedded images all as attachments.  What I'm trying to do is to preserve any attachments that the sender may have attached to the email, but discard any embedded images in the email.

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Bit of a hack but you can search the email content text for the `<img` ... `src=` HTML code which places the image in the email; then you find the name that is referenced in the `src` part of the HTML and then ask mailparser to remove that attachment

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php ? I thought mailparser was some sort of addon you found (because the real function is called mailparse `:-p` ).

Comment: Hi Martin.  Thanks for your reply.  Yes, sorry I mean Mailparse which you linked to.  I'm trying to reduce the number of hacks as much as possible as I already have written code to remove email addresses, phone numbers and links attached to embedded images, all of which work fine. However, these are applied to the mail body post-processing by Mailparse, so by this stage the attachments have already been separated off and saved in a server directory.

Comment: That is the concept of emails -- they have a content body and then attachments, some are inline and some are not. You need to check the document body for the references to inline attachments and then remove the found ones, such as `src="cid:inlineReference"` would mean you'd need to then search the email for the attachment labelled as "inlineReference"

Comment: https://electrictoolbox.com/php-email-extract-inline-image-attachments/ This might be helpful to you.

Comment: From what I can see, Mailparse removes the image filename from the img src so the source code shows src-"cid:[]".  So a possible hack e.g. of finding the srcs, and then using them to delete the extracted images from the server directory, isn't available.  The issue is that this all happensin Mailparse before I can start playing with the mail body code, hence my original question whether in the Mailparse code itself there is the option of discarding rather than saving inlne images.

Comment: I am not sure why you're using Mailparse at all, why not use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? If you're loading emails that have been sent to your server then you should be using a form of email DOM reader to break the email body into its respective parts.

Comment: These are emails that are sent by clients to a given employee's company address.  The incoming emails are piped to the PHP code I'm writing to filter content before being made available to the employee.  The employee can then read the email and reply to the client as needed.  The point of all of this is to remove personal email addresses, phone numbers etc in both directions. It's not a perfect system, but it's what my client wants. Not sure how you would achieve that with PHPMailer.

Comment: Okay, I think I have found the solution in the MimeMailParser.class.php file.  A case of my not seeing the wood for the trees. In the getAttachments 'dispositions', removing the inline option solves the problem.
Thanks for your input.  It kind of pointed me in the right direction! :-)

Comment: Your system sounds like it would be far more efficiently handled by a Perl module that uses the server domain forwarding addresses, but.....

Comment: Outside my knowledge, unfortunately :-)  Always good to learn new stuff, but zero spare time atm due to work.